# How do I re-calculate values in a data frame based on the occurrence of a character (a less-than sign, "<")?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame. Some cells are values only, and some cells are values with a less-than sign ("<"). For example, it looks something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), Y1 = c(5, 2, 7, "< 2", "< 2"), Y2 = c("< 1", 3, 6, "< 1", "< 3"))
```

For every instance of a cell with a less-than sign ("<"), I want to divide the value in the cell by 2. I also want to remove the ‘less than’ sign from the cell to leave just the new, re-calculated value.

All other values (that do not have a less-than sign) would stay the same.

So, it would end up looking like this:

```
df_output <- data.frame(name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), Y1 = c(5, 2, 7, 1, 1), Y2 = c(0.5, 3, 6, 0.5, 1.5))
```

How would I go about doing this? The actual data frame I’m working with is larger (106 columns, 121 rows).

I’m quite new to r. I tried `separate` to separate the “<” from the value, by the space in between (“ “). But this would be laborious with more columns, and also there are many instances where there is no “< " to do a separation. I’m also not sure how best to identify the occurrences of a “<” in order to run the re-calculation on that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R way with a `lapply` loop through the columns and `grepl`.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x){
  i <- grepl("<", x)
  if(any(i)) {
    x <- as.character(x)
    x[i] <- sub("<", "", x[i])
    x <- as.numeric(x)
    x[i] <- x[i]/2
  }
  x
})

df
#  name Y1  Y2
#1    A  5 0.5
#2    B  2 3.0
#3    C  7 6.0
#4    D  1 0.5
#5    E  1 1.5
```

Comment: Thanks Rui. When I run your code at my end, it gives me a warning message about NAs being generated and the resultant df strangely does not match your resultant df (see below). Do you know what might be happening here? 
> df
  name Y1 Y2
1    A  3 NA
2    B  2  3
3    C  4  4
4    D NA NA
5    E NA NA

Comment: @Anna Can you put a `print(x)` statement after the `sub` and say what it prints?

Comment: This is what print(x) - on a new line after the sub line - prints: [1] 5    2    7    <NA> <NA>
Levels: < 2 2 5 7
[1] <NA> 3    6    <NA> <NA>
Levels: < 1 < 3 3 6

Comment: @Anna OK, that output shows that `x` is a factor, so `as.numeric` was failing. See the edit with `x <- as.character(x)` after `if(any(i))`.

Answer (score 1):

This method uses `dplyr` and `stringr` and gets the same results as Rui's answer, but it does give a message about NAs being introduced and I don't know why.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# preserve original
df$Y1raw <- df$Y1
df$Y2raw <- df$Y2

df$Y1 <- case_when(str_starts(df$Y1, "<") ~ 
                     as.numeric(str_remove(df$Y1, "< ")) / 2,
                   TRUE ~ as.numeric(df$Y1))
df$Y2 <- case_when(str_starts(df$Y2, "<") ~ 
                     as.numeric(str_remove(df$Y2, "< ")) / 2,
                   TRUE ~ as.numeric(df$Y2))
df <- df %>% mutate(Y1edit = case_when(Y1 != Y1raw ~ TRUE,
                                  TRUE ~ FALSE)) %>% 
  mutate(Y2edit = case_when(Y2 != Y2raw ~ TRUE,
                            TRUE ~ FALSE))
```

Comment: Thanks markhogue. This works great but longer when there are many more columns of data (in my case, more than 100). I like your idea for tracking modified data. Do you have a suggestion for a function that could do something like that?

Comment: Please see revised answer which adds columns flagging edits.

Answer (score 1):

An economical solution that combines `lapply` with `ifelse`, `grepl`, and `sub`:

```
df[,-1] <- lapply(df[,-1], function(x) ifelse(grepl("<",x), as.numeric(sub("< ", "", x))/2, x))
```

How this works:

- with `df[,-1]`we select the columns that we wish to `lapply`a function to
- with `ifelse` we instruct R to do something if a condition holds
- with `grepl("<",x)`we specifiy the condition (namely that the value contain `<`)
- with `as.numeric(sub("< ", "", x))/2` we state what do if the condition holds: namely first remove `<`  with `sub`, then convert the value to numeric with `as.numeric` and divide it by `2`
- with `x`at the end of the `ifelse` statement we state what is to happen when the condition does *not* apply, namely to be given the value as is.

A `dplyr`solution is this; the logic behind it is essentially the same as above:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(- name), ~ if_else(str_detect(.,"<"), as.numeric(sub("< ", "", .))/2, as.numeric(.)))
```

Result:

```
df
  name Y1  Y2
1    A  5 0.5
2    B  2   3
3    C  7   6
4    D  1 0.5
5    E  1 1.5
```

Comment: Thank you Chris - I like the simplicity of these two options and your explanation is very helpful. Right now, though, when I run your code, the resultant df for me is different to your result. I'm trying to figure out why. The values that once were "<" are accurate (ie. they have been divided by two). But the other values that shouldn't have changed, have changed (see below). This is the same as when I run Rui's code also. If you have any insight, would be much appreciated.  > df
  name Y1  Y2
1    A  3 0.5
2    B  2 3.0
3    C  4 4.0
4    D  1 0.5
5    E  1 1.5

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce `df name Y1 Y2 1 A 3 0.5 2 B 2 3.0 3 C 4 4.0 4 D 1 0.5 5 E 1 1.5` as a dataframe. Which numbers that should not be changed have been changed? Can you give an example? When I run the codes (both mine and Rui's) the resulting numbers are correct.

Comment: Weird. For me, A and C in Y1 (5 and 7) are now 3 and 4, respectively. And C in Y2 (6) is now 4. All these should have stayed unchanged, like they have for you. All other numbers are correct. Is there any reason you can see why your codes would have this different result for me (and also for a colleague of mine who has also tried these lines out)? (To reproduce my resultant dataframe: `df <- data.frame(name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), Y1 = c(3, 2, 4, 1, 1), Y2 = c(0.5, 3.0, 4.0, 0.5, 1.5))`

Comment: Weird indeed. I'm afraid I can't see a reason why. I assume you are using the data as posted by you and the codes as posted by us ... Sorry! Maybe just try again ;)

Comment: Will do. I'll keep puzzling over it and will return to this post when figured out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Rui suggested adding an `as.character(x)` which works on my end. For your line, a similar edit seems to work: `df[,-1] <- lapply(df[,-1], function(x) ifelse(grepl("<",x), as.numeric(sub("< ", "", x))/2, as.character(x)))`